# MySQL: select consecutive ID's as range

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this table

```
+-----+------+
|   ID|Status|
+-----+------+
|    1|     0|
|    2|     1|
|    3|     1|
|    4|     0|
|    5|     1|
|    6|     1|
|    7|     1|
|    8|     1|
|    9|     0|
|   10|     1|
|   12|     1|
+-----+------+
```

I want to select the ID's where Status = 1 as ranges of consecutive values:

```
+-----+-----+
|  Low| High|
+-----+-----+
|    2|    3|
|    5|    8|
|   10|   10|
|   12|   12|
+-----+-----+
```

I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: should't there be 3 result rows? the last tow one combined to "Low = 10 & High = 12"? if not so: why?

Comment: Are we allowed to modify the table structure?

Comment: @EstebanP. There's no ID = 11 record.

Comment: @cgTag Yes, I can have multiple queries before the final query that displays the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a variable and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS low ,MAX(id) AS high
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @row_number:=CASE
            WHEN @id = status THEN @row_number
            ELSE @row_number + 1
        END AS num,
        @id:=status as status,
        id
    FROM tab, (SELECT @row_number:=0, @id := 1) t
    ORDER BY id
) t
WHERE t.status = 1
GROUP BY num
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ba2a6d574aadce279c4d83e9a25421e5)

Comment: MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.  And, it specifically warns against assigning a variable in one expression and using it in another.  This is dangerous, because `@id` is assigned in one expression and used in the other.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Interesting, Even when `ORDER BY` is included? I have tested it with a unordered data and it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by assigning a group to each row.  One method uses a correlated subquery to count the number of *different* statuses before any given one:

```
select status, min(id) as low, max(id) as high
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.id < t.id and t2.status <> t.status
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by status, grp;
```

You can add `where` to either the inner or outer query to limit to `status = 1`.

EDIT:

If performance is an issue, then variables are going to be faster.  I think the simplest method is the version suggested here -- count the number of non-1 values:

```
select status, min(id) as low, max(id) as high
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := (status <> 1)) as grp
      from t cross join 
           (select @grp := 0) params
      order by id
     ) t
where status = 1
group by status, grp;
```

This can also make use of an index on `t(id, status)`.

Comment: I assume that the performance of this on a large table would be poor. Right?

Comment: @cgTag . . . It depends on what you consider a large table, but yes, this scales poorly.

Comment: Large is anything that can't be done in memory without swapping. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misread MySQL for MSSQL. Seems MySQL does not support recursive CTE.

---

Using a recursive CTE:

```
declare @data table(
    ID int not null primary key,
    Status bit not null)

insert into @data
values
(1, 0),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 0),
(5, 1),
(6, 1),
(7, 1),
(8, 1),
(9, 0),
(10, 1),
(12, 1)

;
with dataRecursive as(
    -- anchor
    select      data.ID low,
                data.ID
    from        @data data
    where       data.Status = 1
                and
                not exists(
                    select      1
                    from        @data data_previous
                    where       data_previous.Status = 1
                                and
                                data_previous.ID = data.ID -1
                )
    union all
    -- recursion
    select      dataRecursive.low,
                data_next.ID
    from        @data data_next
                inner join
                dataRecursive
                on  dataRecursive.ID = data_next.ID - 1
    where       data_next.Status = 1
)

select      low,
            MAX(ID) as high
from        dataRecursive
group by    low
order by    low
```